# Desenhar coisas no pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Estou lendo um livro de python teve um codigo que não conseguir entender:
minha duvida

Duvidas:

1.O que é esse get_rect() ?

2.Como funciona essa coisa de tratar coisas como retangulo ?

3.O que é self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect() ?

4.Que é self.rect.centerx = self.screen_rect_centerx ,self.rect.bottom = self.screen_rect.bottom ?

me tirem essas duvidas pfv.

```
import pygame

class nave():
    
    def __init__(self,screen):

        self.tela = tela
        
        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/ship.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

        self.rect.centerx = self.screen_rect_centerx
        self.rect.bottom = self.screen_rect.bottom

    def blitme(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.image,self.rect)
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, com o get_rect() recebes as coordenadas do objecto no ecrã.

Por exe:

```
# Aqui recebes o tamanho da imagem
tamanho = self.image.get_size()
print(tamanho)
```

Vais receber (comprimento, altura) da imagem.

```
# Aqui recebes as coordenadas da imagem.
coordenadas = self.image.get_rect()
print(coordenadas)
```

Vais receber (esquerda, cima, comprimento, altura) que é (x, y, width, height).

O x e y é igual a um ponto no ecrã, o primeiro ponto do rect que fica no canto superior esquerdo, o x é a contagem de píxeis da esquerda para a direita e o y é a contagem de cima para baixo.

Neste caso que recebes o width e height não são coordenadas absolutas de outro ponto do rect no ecrã como o x e o y.

Mas se fosse right e bottom (x, y, right, bottom) é o segundo ponto do rect que fica no canto inferior direito.

Imagina as linhas a sair desses 2 pontos, quando elas se cruzarem fazem o rect.